# Remove item from array if checkbox false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a script that adds items to an array based on the table row being checked. This work well, but I need a way to remove items from the array if the checkbox is unticked. I have tried many variations of splice but don't seem to be getting anywhere. I would be grateful if someone could help modify my code to remove item from the array. Many thanks

```
$(function() {

  info = [];

  $(document).on('click', '.rowChk', function () {

    if ($('.rowChk').is(':checked')) {
    $('#rowClk').show();

    var currentRows = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rackid = currentRows.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    //var rackidnumber = currentRows.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    var rackservice = currentRows.find("td:eq(2)").html();
    var rackactivity = currentRows.find("td:eq(3)").html();
    var rackdept = currentRows.find("td:eq(4)").html();
    var rackcompany = currentRows.find("td:eq(5)").html();
    var rackaddress = currentRows.find("td:eq(6)").html();
    var rackuser = currentRows.find("td:eq(7)").html();
    var rackitem = currentRows.find("td:eq(8)").html();
    var rackddate = currentRows.find("td:eq(9)").html();
    var rackdate = currentRows.find("td:eq(10)").html();

    data = {};

    data.id = rackid;
    //data.idnumber = rackidnumber;
    data.service = rackservice;
    data.activity = rackactivity;
    data.dept = rackdept;
    data.company = rackcompany;
    data.address = rackaddress;
    data.user = rackuser;
    data.item = rackitem;
    data.intakedate = rackdate;
    data.destroydate = rackddate;

    info.push(data);
    //console.log(data);
    } 
    else if ($('.rowChk').prop('checked', false)) {
       var index = info.indexOf($(this).val());
         if (index > -1) {
          info.splice(index, 1);
         }
          console.log("array=[" + info+"]");
         }
    else {
      info.length = 0;
      $('#rowClk').css('display','none');

    }

  });

});

$(function () {

  $(document).on('click', '#rowClk', function () {

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(info);
    //$("#rack").dialog("open");

    console.log(jsonString);
    //$("#rack").dialog("open");

  });
});
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything, surely. You've already checked to see if the checkbox is checked, at that point you're adding the data. If the checkbox isn't checked then don't do anything, right?

Comment: Also, there is no need to create intermediary variables, such as `rackservice`.

Comment: Can you add the html? You're clearly pushing an object into info array and then checking the index of a string.

Comment: Instead of maintaining an array when a row is checked/unchecked, why not just build the array from all known checked boxes once when the button is clicked?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How do I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add or remove items to an array based on the selected state of row checkboxes, you must get the event target first.

```js
$(e.target).is(':checked')
```

If you are adding, you simply add the object to the list. If you want to remove it, you need to get the id of the row.

```js
var recordId = $(e.target).closest('td').text();
```

Then you can just filter it out of the array.

```js
info.filter(record => record.id != recordId);
```

### Demo

```js
loadPlugins(); // Load jQuery plugins

var data = [
  { id : 1, idNumber : 1, service : 1, activity : 1, dept : 1, company : 1, address : 1, user : 1, item : 1, intakeDate : 1, destroyDate : 1 },
  { id : 2, idNumber : 2, service : 2, activity : 2, dept : 2, company : 2, address : 2, user : 2, item : 2, intakeDate : 2, destroyDate : 2 },
  { id : 3, idNumber : 3, service : 3, activity : 3, dept : 3, company : 3, address : 3, user : 3, item : 3, intakeDate : 3, destroyDate : 3 },
  { id : 4, idNumber : 4, service : 4, activity : 4, dept : 4, company : 4, address : 4, user : 4, item : 4, intakeDate : 4, destroyDate : 4 }
];

$(function() {
  var info = []; // Running list...
  $.tableFromJson(data).appendTo('body');

  $('table tbody tr td:first-child')
    .each((i, td) => $(td).prepend($('<input type="checkbox">').addClass('row-chk')));

  $(document).on('click', '.row-chk', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(':checked')) {
      let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
      let data = {
        id : currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(),
        idNumber : currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(),
        service : currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(),
        activity : currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(),
        dept : currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(),
        company : currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(),
        address : currentRow.find("td:eq(6)").text(),
        user : currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text(),
        item : currentRow.find("td:eq(8)").text(),
        intakeDate : currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").text(),
        destroyDate : currentRow.find("td:eq(10)").text()
      };
      info.push(data); // Add
    } else {
      let $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');                   // Unused
      let rowIndex = $tr.index();                            // Unused
      let recordId = $(e.target).closest('td').text();
      removeAllFromArray(info, 'id', recordId);              // In-place removal
      //info = info.filter(record => record.id != recordId); // Remove (modifies)
    }
    
    var selectedRows = $(e.target).closest('table').getCheckedRowData();
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedRows)); // Live state from the table...
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info));         // Running list...
  });
});

// Defined as a plugin belowL $.fn.getCheckedRowData
function getCheckedRowData($table) {
  var headers = $table.find('thead th').map((row, th) => $(th).text()).toArray();
  return $table.find('tbody tr').reduce((records, tr, row) => {
    if ($(tr).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
      records.push($(tr).find('td').reduce((obj, cell, col) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, { [headers[col]] : $(cell).text() });
      }, {}));
    }
    return records;
  }, []);
}

function removeAllFromArray(arr, prop, val) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i][prop] === val) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

function loadPlugins() {
  (function($) {
    $.reduce = function(arr, fnReduce, valueInitial) {
      if (Array.prototype.reduce) {
        return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arr, fnReduce, valueInitial);
      }
      $.each(arr, function(i, value) {
        valueInitial = fnReduce.call(null, valueInitial, value, i, arr);
      });
      return valueInitial;
    };
    $.fn.reduce = function(fnReduce, valueInitial) {
      return $.reduce(this, fnReduce, valueInitial);
    };
    $.fn.renderTable = function(data, options) {
      options = options || {};
      let ignoreCase = options.ignoreCase, fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
      return this.renderHeaders(fields).renderRows(fields, data);
    };
    $.fn.renderHeaders = function(fields) {
      return this.append($.renderHeaders(fields));
    }
    $.fn.renderRows = function(fields, data) {
      return this.append($.renderRows(fields, data));
    };
    $.tableFromJson = function(data, options) {
      return $('<table>').renderTable(data, options)
        .toggleClass('stylized', (options || {}).stylized);
    };
    $.renderHeaders = function(fields) {
      return $('<thead>').append($('<tr>').append(fields
        .map(field => $('<th>')
          .append($('<div>').text(field)))));
    };
    $.renderRows = function(fields, data) {
      return $('<tbody>').append(data
        .map((rec, row) => $('<tr>').append(fields
          .map((field, col) => $('<td>').text(rec[field]).data('field-name', field)))));
    };
    $.fn.getCheckedRowData = function() {
      return getCheckedRowData(this);
    };
  })(jQuery);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0.75em;
  margin-bottom: 0.33em;
}

table.stylized {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 600px;
}

table.stylized thead th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #039;
  background: #b9c9fe;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.stylized thead th input {
  background: #f2f5ff;
  color: #039;
  font-size: smaller;
}

table.stylized tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f2f5ff;
}

table.stylized tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e8edff;
}

table.stylized tbody td {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #669;
  padding: 6px;
}

table.stylized tbody tr:hover td {
  background: #d0dafd;
}

table.stylized tbody tr td:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em !important;
}

table.stylized tbody tr td:first-child input {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the markup. However, I feel this i overkill as all I am trying to do is remove an item from array if checkbox is unchecked. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I showed you how to simply add/remove, I provided a small example because you did not do so... The `Array.prototype.filter` call returns an array without the item... If you want it optimized (only splices...), I can edit the response...

Comment: @user1532468 Created a function to do an in-place removal from the `info` array and an alternative function to grab selected row data right off of the table.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I shall piece it all together and hopefully it shall work.